# Gram-Schmidt pan-sharpening in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, remote-sensing, pansharpening

I need to perform **Gram-Schmidt** pan-sharpening, I don't have access to ArcGIS or ENVI so have been using **QGIS**. Is there any plug-in or similar capability that is available to perform Gram-Schmidt pan-sharpening in QGIS? If not, is this possible in any other open-source software?

Comment: I don't think QGIS has such a pan-sharpening method. **GRASS's** `i.pansharpen` tool has three methods: _IHS_, _Brovey_, and _PCA_. The Orfeo Toolbox has another three methods: _RCS_, _Bayesian Fusion_ and _Local Mean and Variance Matching_.

Comment: @Joseph I specifically require Gram-Schmidt pan-sharpening - If I understand you (and from what I found when googling), is it correct that GRASS doesn't have this capability?

Comment: I do not think GRASS has this method (atleast I couldn't find it).

Comment: According to harrisgeospatial.com, "You can also write a script to perform pan sharpening using..." http://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/envigramschmidtpansharpeningtask.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the comments above at the moment the is no such functionality in QGIS.
You could try to implement your own plug-in to perform this task by using this scientific paper: [How to pan-sharpen images using the Gram-Schmidt pan-sharpen method-a recipe](https://www.int-arch-photogramm-remote-sens-spatial-inf-sci.net/XL-1-W1/239/2013/isprsarchives-XL-1-W1-239-2013.pdf)

Comment: Here's the original patent, which expired in 2018: https://patents.google.com/patent/US6011875A/en